# while android device is in splite screen mode, how to detect which application is recently used?

Tags: android

In **splite-screen** mode in android device, two application can be on screen with partition ,how to detect which application is in front with its screen bound.

Answer (score 0):

The application that is currently is in use will be in the `resumed` state, while the other activity will be `paused` when it looses focus.

Comment: Thanks ! also want to know size of both app on screen. if you please share the code for the same.